# Insert data on xml file on web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to insert data between specific tag inside my xml file , The code works well on my computer but when I run it on the web it Does not insert the data between the specific tag like that :
this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
<channel>

</channel>
</rss>
```

I want to insert data inside "channel" tag .
this is my code it's working fine ! :

```
FilePath = "h:\root\home\karary-001\www\site1\xmlfile1.xml" **//this is path to my xml file on website**
    Dim document As New XDocument
    document = XDocument.Load(FilePath)
    Dim root = New XElement("item")
    Dim title = New XElement("title", New XCData(TextBox3.Text))
    Dim link = New XElement("link", TextBox6.Text)
    root.Add(title, link)
    document.Root.Elements.First().Add(root)
    document.Save(FilePath)
    Label1.Text = "! done"
```

when I change FilePath ="C:\Users\MONZER\Downloads\XMLFile1.xml" :
I get this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel>
<item>
<title><![CDATA[ title]]></title>
<link>http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com</link>
<pubDate>2018/08/06 06:20</pubDate>
<description><![CDATA[fsdsdsdsgntbx cfv]]></description>
<media.thumbnail url="http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com/images/" height="266" width="127" />
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

but when I use FilePath ="h:\root\home\karary-001\www\site1\xmlfile1.xml" :
I get this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
***<channel></channel>***
<item>
<title><![CDATA[ title]]></title>
<link>http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com</link>
<pubDate>2018/08/06 06:20</pubDate>
<description><![CDATA[fsdsdsdsgntbx cfv]]></description>
<media.thumbnail url="http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com/images/" height="266" width="127" />
</item>
</rss>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between two FilePath. Could you edit your question?

Comment: the two XML samples appear to be identical at a glance. If there's a problem you'll need to be more specific about it than just "doesn't work"

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.